# Non-blocking webpack watch with grunt-webpack

Tags: webpack, gruntjs, webpack-2

Is there a way to configure the grunt-webpack plugin to avoid blocking other grunt watch tasks from running when using webpack with watch? I know there are grunt plugins out there to spawn tasks in a separate process, but it would be great to be able to do this from within the plugin configuration.